# I have issue with x11 display variable on ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: laravel, jasper-reports, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem with `jasper` report with `laravel` on ubuntu 16.04 server.

The error shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.<init>(JasperViewer.java:267)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.viewReport(JasperViewer.java:655)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.viewReport(JasperViewer.java:587)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.viewReport(JasperViewer.java:535)
        at de.cenote.jasperstarter.Report.view(Report.java:318)
        at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.processReport(App.java:264)
        at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.main(App.java:102)
```

Noted: on my local computer it's working so fine.

Anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JasperViewer.viewReport should not be used in web applications, this is a swing (installed app) function, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37686024/5292302, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785195

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks